# Commenting "the rails way" - regarding table relationships and the rails way or tackling problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, comments, table-relationships

I'm looking to implement a site wide comment/message feature into my apps entities. This will enable people to comment on the following modules

```
Newsletters
Reports
Tasks
and user to user (messaging)
```

My plan would be to make a foreign key called "entity_id" which doesn't relate to any single table. Instead, it's coupled with commentEntity_id which is a list of all the tables that can be commented on.

Example:

So a comment would have a CommentEntity which points to **Reports** and also an entity_id which, in this case, is the id of the Reports table.

The way I would build this is to make the following tables

```
 Comment #along with user_id and a comment body:string, this will also have a commentEntity_id and a entity_id 

 CommentInvolvement # simply everyone involved (either by commenting on the entity, or in the case of user to user, **being** the entity)

 CommentEntity # This is the join between the comment and the place
 it's put.
```

This would be my solution in a PHP project, though I understand Rails requires a different way of thinking, so I would like to get the community's thoughts on this problem, and wheather this is the best way to tackle it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Rails supports this approach through [Polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

comment.rb

```
belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
```

other models

```
has_many :comments, as: :commentable
```

Note: You have to add two columns in comments table `commentable_id`(Integer) and `commentable_type`(String)

Answer (score 0):

you should also check out the great [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised) regarding Polymorphic Associations
d